# TCP/IP is part of operating system or we can create our own?

Tags: android, tcp

I'm a new comer in network technology, is TCP/IP protocols are part of the operating system or we can create our own.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP is part of an operating system and you can create your userspace TCP/IP

for example, a popular one: [picotcp](https://github.com/tass-belgium/picotcp)

Comment: Can I make my own TCP/IP and run it in my own pc

Comment: Can I customize tcp ip of my system.

Comment: @Vijaydidmca1234 yes, you can build a custom TCP/IP and use it instead use system one in your code.